# Constructing P-value for replicates in linear model in R

Tags: r, regression

Say I have two repeats of the same predictor measurements of continuous nature and a single continuous dependable. How can I compute a single p-value for the association of the predictor with the dependable.

Here an example:

```
input <- data.frame(
Dependent = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30),
R1 = c(5, 7, 10, 12, 15) + rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 2), 
R2 = c(5, 7, 10, 12, 15) + rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 2)
)
```

Currently, I get two p-values but I would like to report a single p-value for the null hypothesis of no association of predictor with dependable.

Repeats here are defined in a medical/biological sense. The same type of measurement was performed on two different days. The goal is to link these measurements to a different type of measurement that was only collected once. Each row of the data.frame constitutes paired observations and as such can be compared.

Comment: Why are you having "repeats" of the same predictor? In this case they are not actually repeats...they are two randomly simulated variables with no correlation to each other or the dependent variable. I'm guessing this doesn't fit whatever use case you are considering if this is supposed to resemble data you are currently working with. I would clarify what "repeats" are here and perhaps add some explanation about why you think this is an issue. Otherwise its hard to answer this question directly.

Comment: Suggested edits attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "replicate" here, but when I ran your code, I got four p values. One for the intercept, one for R1, one for R2 and one for the whole model. This last was printed under the table of parameter estimates.

Call:
lm(formula = Dep ~ R1 + R2, data = input)

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3060 -0.6317 -0.0152  0.6468  3.2581 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.02794    0.03153  -0.886   0.3758  
R1           0.05818    0.03215   1.809   0.0707 .
R2           0.01715    0.03117   0.550   0.5823  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9966 on 997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.00351,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.001511 
F-statistic: 1.756 on 2 and 997 DF,  p-value: 0.1733
```

This is exactly what I expected.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Replicates here are two independent experiments of the same type. Thanks for pointing out the p-value for the whole model. Could you help me understand which null hypothesis is tested by the p-value of the whole model?

Comment: It's testing whether the F statistic is 0, which is roughly like asking if the whole model is sig.